# Determine whether a value is a function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeinfo

Is it possible to write a function `isFunc :: a -> Bool` to determine whether an arbitrary value is a function (of any kind) such that

```
foo :: Int -> Int
bar :: Char -> Char -> Char    

> isFunc foo
True
> isFunc bar
True
> isFunc 3
False
> isFunc 'a'
False
```

I'm using [Data.Dynamic](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Dynamic.html) so I can't determine the type in advance.

Comment: `isFunc` isn't a well-formed question to ask in the presence of polymorphism. I have a thing of type `a`; is it a function or not? The answer is indeterminate until I've turned `a` into a monomorphic type, since until then I could choose, for example, `a ~ Int` or `a ~ Int -> Int`. Your `isFunc 3` example has exactly this problem, and you probably didn't even notice; how do you know `3` isn't a function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Parametricity says no. The only functions of type

```
a -> Bool
```

are constant functions.

However, with a bit of ad hoc polymorphism and a bit more chutzpah, you can do this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Sick x where
  isFunc :: x -> Bool

instance Sick (a -> b) where
  isFunc _ = True

instance Sick x where
  isFunc _ = False
```

and then it looks like you have

```
*Sick> isFunc 3
False
*Sick> isFunc id
True
```

But it does seem like a peculiar thing to do. What use is the resulting `Bool` to you?

Comment: I'm mapping over a list of dynamically typed values and applying x to those that are functions.

Comment: I'm not convinced this approach will actually work for that problem -- or, frankly, that _any_ approach will work for that problem, in Haskell.  Typeclass instances in Haskell are always resolved at compile time, not runtime, and the situation you describe seems to require runtime resolution.

Answer (score 11):

What are you asking for and what you need to do with `Data.Dynamic` seem to be different things. You need to know the exact type of value before extracting it with `fromDyn`/`fromDynamic`. To determine whether `Dynamic` contains a function value you need to analyze `TypeRep`:

```
isFuncDynamic x = typeRepTyCon (dynTypeRep x) == typeRepTyCon (typeOf2 id)
```

(Forgive me if this is not the most concise implementation.)

Comment: Thanks. This function (albeit manually constructed) is just what I was looking for.